# Detect head tilt in a image

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, image, image-processing

I am suppose to detect if there is a head tilt in photos. These photos are identity card size photos or passport size photos. If a head tilt is detected, then I need to correct / rectify the tilt error by rotating the image clockwise or anticlockwise.

I want to know if there is any open source library or dll that can be used in the project that will help me detect face & facial features like eyes and ears.

The detection must be done on the fly as there will be a 1000's of images opened from a directory.

I've gone through http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/462527/Camera-Face-Detection-in-Csharp-Using-Emgu-CV-Open tutorial, but did not solve my problem. Also I've gone through EmguCV's eg. Example.FaceDetection.exe in the bin folder, but it does not detect the face. I tried loading other images as well, but still the same & no highlighting of face or facial features.

Comment: @jamesj I've re edited my question. Please let me know your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a library for face detection, look at the height of the eyes and establish the tilt of the face. If the angle is within +/-5 degrees of horizontal, apply the rotation to the image by drawing the image to a new new image with a rotation.

Face detection in C# example (easily converted to VB.NET) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/462527/Camera-Face-Detection-in-Csharp-Using-Emgu-CV-Open

Note: it is assumed that you have pictures of people looking straight into the camera, such as passport photos, that you want to straighten. For a photo where a person is looking slightly sideways, the angle of the camera will make the eyes be non level even if the persons head is not tilted.

Comment: I like your idea of detecting the height of eyes from top, but can you guide me in which library or dll should be used for detection. I need to detect facial feature from images. I tried Emgu but not understanding it quite well.

Comment: The linked example has both a downloadable example with source, as well as the explanation in the article. I can't describe it in any more detail than that here.